# Changing XML color from java code

Tags: java, android, xml, colors

I want a `button` shaped as a circle which i can change the background color of from my `.java` file.

I dont want to use circular images which change to accomplish this because i want to potentially use any hex color and i would need far too many images.

I have created an `XML` file called roundbutton which displays a round button by using 45 corner radius, but i need to be able to change the colour attribute(`android:color="#ff0000"` for instance)
from my .java

The round button displays ok right now but only displaying the colour i have set in the xml file, If I use `buttonname.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));` the circle will be replaced by a square, so using the XML colour attribute would work if only i could change it from `.java`!

By the way im changing the colour of this round button on the press of another button.

hope this makes sense, thanks in advance!

XML circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />  <<<<NEED TO CHANGE THE COLOUR CODE HERE FROM WITHIN .JAVA
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="45dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="45dp"  
    android:topRightRadius="45dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="45dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: try this.... buttonname.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#002300"));

Comment: Using this has the same effect as .setBackgroundColor(color.RED) the custom shape is replaced with a colored square. a change in the XML attribute seems the only way

Comment: what u exactly want..... chaning the button color or button shape??

Comment: I simply want to change the colour of the custom round button I have created however when changing the background color it changes to a square of the colour i selected rather than changing the circle shaped button to a different color.

Answer (score 0):

use `.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_in_xmlfile));` in `onClickListener()` on button which you want to press for changing color else use

```
View.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E7FC3A"));
```

and if you are using .java file i.e dunamically than dont set color from .xml file else it will not show effect on Orientation change

Comment: Using this has the same effect as .setBackgroundColor(color.RED) the custom shape is replaced with a colored square. a change in the XML attribute seems the only way.

Comment: see edited answer and if this doesnot satisfy your need than please be more clear so that i can help u

Comment: I need to be able to edit the XML colour attribute from .java

Comment: values defined in xml file like String.xml, style.xml, color.xml are purely static once you define resource in xml file you cannot change it at run time

Answer (score 0):

Create another shape xml which have different color and access file using `.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_in_xmlfile));`

Comment: surely i would need to creae a shape for each colour, and there could be any number of possibilities.